# open function in Linux Programmer Guide

Tags: c, manpage

In Linux Programmer Guide(man 2)(left), there is two open function like c++ overload but in POSIX programmer guide(man 3)(right) there is one. What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: What is the signature of the one at `man 3 open`?

Comment: It is a different way to describe the same function: right one use variable arguments while left one defines all possible parameters